# How to show month and year in the x axis name in highcharts

Tags: highcharts, angular15

I am trying to show past 3 month with year in the y axis value in highcharts. but it is not working it is coming like 0 1 2 3 4...

I want to show like ( Apr 2023   May 2023 Jun 2023) in the x axis.

```
   xAxis: {
  type: 'year',
  dateTimeLabelFormats: {
    // do display the month and year
    month: '%b %y',
    year: '%Y',
  },
  },
```

Demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-cloning-barchart-wpj4ti?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `xAxis.type: 'datetime'` and `xAxis.dateTimeLabelFormats` set to `month: '%b %Y`'. Besides that, you need to also define `x` values as a `timestamp` or alternatively set `pointStart` and `pointInterval` options.

**Demo:**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-cloning-barchart-npvldx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

API References:
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.type
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.dateTimeLabelFormats

Comment: You have used like  pointStart: Date.UTC(2023, 3, 1) for 2023. So, What happened for next year. Every year i want to update the year in the code ??

Comment: It all depends on your requirements and data that you represent on the chart. This is an example only, but if you want, e.g. get the current year, you can achieve it by JS Date() object and it's methods, as follows: https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-cloning-barchart-adiosw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Can you answer this : 76774162